# Configure Wildfly/Undertow to exchange jsessionid as HTTP Header?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-8, jsessionid

The jsessionid to manage the session can be configured with tracking-mode in mode cookie or URL mode.

Example jsessionid mode cookie:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: jsessionid=WuscHxD4eZCkPXDPubheV9MC.mbp-de-sadsad
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
```

Example jsessionid mode url:

http://www.example.com/home;jsessionid=BB69F0DEF79877629096AFEFFB53D478

Is there any way to configure or extend the behavior of wildfly (8.0.1 for sharing jsessionid via HTTP Header?

Example of what I need:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
jsessionid: WuscHxD4eZCkPXDPubheV9MC.mbp-de-kdslsd
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
```

Is it possible to configure Wildfly(8.1.0/8.2.0)/Undertow to exchange jsessionid as HTTP Header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible with configuration only. You could do it with code though. But accessing the sessionId-suffix isn't possible in a portable manner ,since it's not part of the servlet specification. Thus I used request/response rewriting capabilities of my load-balancer instead, when having been confronted with the same problem.

The sessionId suffix is the ".mbp-de-kdslsd" part. [Wildfly uses the jboss.node.name for this.](https://developer.jboss.org/message/879684)

If you want to do it with code, you should [hook the sending of a response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) and add a Header [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html). The sessionId is available from a [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) using a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). I don't know of the top of my head how to access the jboss.node.name property, but I'm pretty sure the [quickstart-samples](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/search?q=jboss.node.name) will have some code for you.